# Jenkins Workspaces are not created for Parallel Stages created inside the Pipeline Script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Jenkins Custom Workspaces are not created for Parallel Stages created inside the Pipeline Script

Only the main Custom Workspace "main_ws" is created.

Why are Custom Workspaces for parallel script-generated stages not created and how can I fix this?

```
def getTests(Name, Versions) {
    return Versions.collectEntries { version ->
        [
                (version): {
                    stage("${Name}:${version} Tests") {
                        agent {
                            node {
                                label "docker"
                                customWorkspace "${Name}${version}"
                            }
                        }
                        script {
                            bat "echo Testing the ${Name}:${version}"
                        }
                    }
                }
        ]
    }
}


pipeline {
  agent {
    label "docker"
  }

  tools {
    gradle "gradle"
  }

  parameters {
    text(name: 'VERSIONS', defaultValue: '1.0\n2.0\n3.0\n', description: '')
    booleanParam(name: 'NAME', defaultValue: false, description: '')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Tests') {
      parallel {
        stage('Tests') {
          when {
            expression {
              return params.NAME
            }
          }
          agent {
            node {
              label "docker"
              customWorkspace "main_ws"
            }
          }
          steps {
            script {
              def versions = params.VERSIONS.split("\n")
              parallel getTests("NAME", versions)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarative syntax *inside* scripted syntax doesn't work the same way as outside. Outside the `script` step `pipeline` and `stage` are keywords and accept `agent` keyword. Inside the `script` step `pipeline` and `stage` are *steps* that know nothing `agent` keyword anymore. The corresponding scripted syntax is `node` and `ws`, see [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#node-allocate-node).